# What are the drawbacks of devise lockable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I understand devise lockable is a beneficial solution to prevent brute force attacks and random hacking attempts on a users account. However I can't help but think the lockable solution could be abused by those who know of it. For example, could somebody purposely continue to wrongly guess another’s password with the intent of locking them out their account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So litmus test for me is 'is this better or worse than not doing it'.   Any system could be used to dos an account but this increases security in most cases.  That is why I use it.

Comment: I get how it's beneficial and prevents much worse things. But not everyone will brute force a password, however the likelihood of someone locking someone’s account is a lot higher.

Comment: What are you basing that assertion on?  I am not going off of hard data but i do know that there are far fewer people who understand this well enough to know how to denial of service an account than there are people who know how to guess a password for someone's email account.  So it increases security.

Comment: It's not the breaking into the account I worry about at this stage, it's more of the inconvenience for a user to be consistently locked out their own account if users discover they can lock accounts from failed log in attempts